# How to load image dynamically when the image is connected to ftp server?

Tags: jquery, html, jsp

The image src is connected to the ftp server. I don't know in what ways I can load the image that is in the ftp server.

**JSP side**

```
 <c:choose>

 <c:when test="${i.objThomasian.entryYear <= 1999}">

 <img src="path in the ftp server" class="img-fluid" id="imageholder" onload="loadImageOldEntryYearStudent('${i.id}')"/>  

</c:when>

<c:otherwise>

<img src="path in the ftp server" class="img-fluid" id="imageholder" onload="loadImageNewEntryYearStudent('${i.objThomasian.entryYear},${i.id}')"/> 

</c:otherwise>

</c:choose>
```

Comment: **Jquery Side**
 this contains the process of loading the different images dynamically
 function loadImageOld(id) {
  var img = new Image();
  var Boolean;
  $(img).load(function () {
           Boolean = true;
            });
            img.src = "path in the ftp server/"+id+"p.jpg";
    }
            function loadImageNew(entryYear,id) {
            var img = new Image();
            var Boolean;
            $(img).on('load',function () {
               Boolean = true;
            });
            img.src = "path in the ftp server/"+entryYear+"/"+id+"p.jpg";
            }